# Не получается достать число из SharedPreferences, что я делаю не так?

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Мне нужно сохранить цифру 5, я делаю это так

```
sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor ed = sPref.edit();
ed.putInt(SCHETCHIK, 5);
ed.commit();
```

Затем мне нужно достать эту 5 из другого класса, я делаю это так

```
sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
schPrin = sPref.getInt(SCHETCHIK, 0);
```

Но вместо цифры 5 я получаю 0 или ту что поставлю вместо нуля, как мне вытащить мою цифру 5 из SharedPreferences?

Comment: Шётчик. Ну не используйте вы транслит, умоляю. Ну зачем так. Тратьте хотя бы 10 секунд на гугл перевод, я уже не говорю про изучение английского.

Comment: Я разобрался, ошибка была другом, у меня не сохранялся ed.putInt(SCHETCHIK, 5);, а sPref.getInt(SCHETCHIK, 0); выводил при этом то что указано вместо 0, когда 5 сохранилась то все заработала, ошибка у меня была в другом в условии if else, код действительно рабочий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил ваш код у себя, работает! Почитайте [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences), попробуйте другой способ.

Comment: Спасибо ваш комментарий помог мне разобраться.